# Snap.svg - How to load SVGs synchronous?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Knowing that `Snap.load();` is asynchronous, I'm looking for a way to append the loaded files in the requested order. This is the code I'm using:

```
s = Snap(800, 800);

function loadSvg(url) {
    Snap.load(url, appendSvg);
};

function appendSvg(svg) {
    g = svg.select("g");
    s.append(g);
};

loadSvg('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9473/b.svg');
loadSvg('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9473/a.svg');
```

I found this (http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-loadmulti.html), but I wonder if there's any simpler, official **Snap.svg**, way to do it? For me it feels that the `Snap.load();` should have a feature for this included?

Comment: `For me it feels that the Snap.load(); should have a feature for this included?` - it doesn't. The code in the link you provided provides the solution elegantly

Comment: I wrote that plugin, as I'm not aware of any way to load multiple files synchronous like that within the library. Don't be too afraid of plugins though, they are useful way to add solutions.

Comment: Another solution could be to simply include all of the SVGs inside a group or svg tag as a single file and load that.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. The reason I'm looking for another way is because I'm quite new to JS and I felt your plugin might be too advanced for me. However, I will be sure to try it out. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sequence asynchronous tasks nicely with [Javascript promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) ([polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/) for platforms that do not yet have native Promise), e.g.:

```
// Helper to convert Snap.load() into a Promise.
function loadSVG(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Snap.load(url, resolve);
  });
};

// Make an array of Promises.
var loadPromises = [
  loadSVG('http://example.com/a.svg'),
  loadSVG('http://example.com/b.svg'),
  loadSVG('http://example.com/c.svg'),
  ...
];

// Wait for all the Promises to finish.
Promise.all(loadPromises).then(function(results) {
  // results contains the loaded SVGs, in order.
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
    var svg = results[i];

    // Your processing of each SVG goes here.
    var g = svg.select("g");
    s.append(g);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working good and is quite simple to understand! However, how would you do if you'd like to add a shape in between the loaded SVGs?

For example:
`var loadPromises = [
  loadSVG('http://example.com/a.svg'),
  s.circle(100, 100, 50),
  loadSVG('http://example.com/b.svg')
];`

I tried it but the circle ended up being appended before the loaded content.

Comment: The code in your comment is wrong for two reasons. First, [`circle()`](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.circle) inserts a new element immediately. Second, all the elements of an array passed to `Promise.all()` must be a `Promise`. You could instead use something like `Promise.resolve(Snap.fragment('<circle x="0" y="0" r="20">'))`, where the outer `Promise.resolve()` function wraps its argument with a `Promise`.

Comment: @rhashimoto Thanks just what I needed.