# How to load SVG synchronous by using snap.svg in Angular 2 component constructor?

Tags: angular, promise, observable, snap.svg

Please point me. I know snap.load() is a async call but I want to make it synchronously inside of component constructor so that when construction finish I have have all the svg elements ready for use, or assign the elements to child components. Something like this. So basically, how can I block constructor until snap.load completed?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from 'child.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  svgPath: string = "assets/svg/sprites.svg"
  SVGElements: any;

  constructor(){
    var self = this;
    
    Snap.load(svgPath, function(items) {
      
      items.selectAll().forEach(function(item) {
        var clone = item.clone()        
        self.SVGElements.push(clone);
      });      

    }

    //this show empty, I know because snap.load is an async call 
    console.log(this.SVGElements);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //I want to do something with this.SVGElements here
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot make an async function synchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snap.svg - How to load SVGs synchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430162/snap-svg-how-to-load-svgs-synchronous)